# Animation not working unless you are resizing the frame

Tags: java, user-interface

I have this GUI class in Java:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class GUI extends JFrame {
    private boolean[][] board;
    private int width; 
    private int height;
    private int multiplier = 25;
    private int xMarginLeft = 2;
    private int xMarginRight = 1;
    private int yMarginBottom = 3;
    private int yMarginTop = 2;

    public GUI(boolean[][] board) {
        this.width = GameOfLife.getNextBoard().length + xMarginLeft;
        this.height = GameOfLife.getNextBoard()[0].length + yMarginBottom;
        setTitle("John Conway's Game of Life");
        setSize(width * multiplier, height * multiplier);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        board = GameOfLife.getNextBoard();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width * multiplier, height * multiplier);
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j]) {
                    g.fillRect((i + xMarginRight) * multiplier, (j + yMarginTop) * multiplier, multiplier - 1, multiplier - 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is a snippet from the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI boardGraphics = new GUI(nextBoard);
    boolean[][] board = new boolean[nextBoard.length][nextBoard[0].length];
    for (int gen = 0; gen < 25; gen++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nextBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nextBoard[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = nextBoard[i][j];
            }
        }
        try {
            boardGraphics.paint(null);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {}
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                if (board[i][j] && !(countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 2 || countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 3)) {
                    nextBoard[i][j] = false;
                }
                else if (!board[i][j] && countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 3) {
                    nextBoard[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
```

However, when I run the program, the animation only works if I'm resizing/minimising/maximising the frame. Is this completely the wrong approach to animation? Or is my code incorrect in some way?

Comment: I can't see where the painting of the board is being kept running, I only see one call to paint with a null parameter. I will suggest you to build the board class extending from a panel and manage all the refreshes on that and not directly over a `JFrame`.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) Change code of the form `catch (Exception e) { ..` to `catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); // very informative! ..` 3) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are right: this *is* the wrong approach to animation:

1. you must run all code that accesses GUI classes on the Event Dispatch Thread;
2. animation is implemented by scheduling a repeated task on Swing's `Timer`, and never using a loop that involves `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Well, I think using a loop is also a valid approach for this kind of procedures, @Marko Topolnik, but surely will be harder to control the frame/refresh rate. Of course with swing's Timer, all of that hassle becomes easy to work with.

Comment: @Noe If you go for a loop, that means you are basically reimplementing a task scheduler: you'll have a thread that doesn't do anything but wait 99% of the time, and all the actual work it does is submitting a `Runnable` to the EDT. There is really little benefit to that approach, except that it is slightly more convenient to control the number of animation steps.